# how to change php version on git hub codespace?

Tags: php, ubuntu, github-codespaces

I am working on the codespace on some PHP-based code. when I am running this command:

> php --ini

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /opt/php/8.2.4/ini
Loaded Configuration File:         /opt/php/8.2.4/ini/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /opt/php/8.2.4/ini/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

So I install PHP v7.4 by using this command:

> sudo apt install php7.4-common

and when I am trying to `update-alternatives --config php` it says:

> There is only one alternative in link group php (providing /usr/bin/php): /usr/bin/php7.4
> Nothing to configure.

but my code has some dependencies on php7.4 and still I cannot run my code completly.7
the `php --ini` command also returns the same result.

the `php --version` returns **PHP 8.2.4**

Comment: and what would you get if `update-alternatives --config` is run **before** you install 7.4?

Comment: I am getting:
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for php

Comment: The github codespaces is using docker images. If your code depends on php 7.4 imho it would be better to use the php 7.4 image instead of trying to install php 7.4 in php 8.2 image.

Comment: how can I change the image version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that said php8 is installed outside package manager for some reasons? But regardless of that you may still invoke any binary you want by providing full path to it, so instead of doing

```bash
$ composer install
```

you can just do

```bash
$  /usr/bin/php7.4 composer install
```

which will run composer using 7.4. If you want to dig deeper, you need to check your `$PATH` as it can have `/opt/php` prioritized.

**EDIT:** as `composer` is now argument to PHP, it will no longer be automatically located by the shell, so you need to provide full path to `composer` if it's not in your current directory. You can get it with i.e. `which composer` or you can make you shell invocation like this (assuming it's bash):

```bash
$ /usr/bin/php7.4 "$(which composer)" install
```

which (assuming composer is in your `$PATH`) should solve the problem.

Alternatively, if there's a possibility, you can check if you can use dedicated image with PHP7.4 - that'd be much cleaner approach.

Comment: /usr/bin/php7.4 composer install returns this error. `Could not open input file: composer`

Answer (score 0):

In Github Codespaces you can install different platforms and versions with Oryx:

`oryx prep --skip-detection --platforms-and-versions 'php=8.1'`

find out the installed version:
`ll /opt/php/`

Symlink the correct version:
`sudo ln -s /opt/php/8.1.27/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php81`

you now have php8.1 installed.
`php81 -v`